# Updating a 2D Array with the output results of a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a nested loop where I calculate 10 distances, and store them in an array `b_array`. Then into `a_array` another array which will is to keep the results for every image. The problem is that my code overwrites `a_array` for every iteration even when it is outside the main function when I checked with `print`. Therefore, I end up with the exact same result of the last executed file in the loop for all 4 images.

```
distances = np.linspace(min_distance, max_distance, 10)
a_array = np.zeros((4,10))
  
    for x in range (0, 4):
        b_array = np.zeros(10)
        for y in range(0,10):
            b_array[y] = mean_intensity(distances)#local function
        a_array[x] = b_array
        print(a_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a (4,10) array with each row as evenly spaced numbers, then you could do: `np.linspace([min_distance]*4, [max_distance]*4, 10, axis=1)`, which would have the same effect as:

```
min_distance = 0
max_distance = 10
a_array = np.zeros((4,10))

for x in range (0, 4):
    b_array = np.linspace(min_distance, max_distance, 10)
    a_array[x] = b_array
```